# AWS ECS Fargate udp multicast between containers within VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc, multicast, aws-fargate

I would like to deploy udp multicast sender and receiver on ECS Fargate within the same VPC. I follow Transit gateway multicast instruction but seems works only for EC2.

I'm wondering is ECS fargate support multicast?

AWS mentions

> A non-Nitro instance cannot be a multicast sender

Is fargate use non-Nitro instance by default? or is it configurable?

Very appreciate for any helps, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a blog post on AWS on how to set up udp multicast on ECS:

https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-ecs-multicast-sample

The page states that the following requirements must be met:

- A VPC, with a pair of public and private subnets spread across two
  Availability Zones
- An Internet Gateway and NAT gateways
- A Transit Gateway with VPC attachments
- A Multicast Domain with subnet associations
- ECS Cluster
- EC2-based container instances configured to support IGMP version 2
- Container images capable of sending and receiving multicast

The page also states that Fargate is not yet supported, only on instance backed ECS clusters. So looks like the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

I tried multiple days with different EC2 instances of Nitro enclave AWS but the example (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/running-multicast-enabled-containers-on-aws/) which aws has given not working out for me. Most of the time only one receiver was receiving the multicast traffic and rarely all the receivers were receiving the traffic. I used EC2 deployment in ECS with networkmode host to get it worked. This set up is working reliably for me.